# Binary refused IOS, crash on launch

Tags: ios, swift, binary, app-store-connect

I have searched on the web and here for 20 hours, and I don't know what's wrong with my app.
My app was refused by Apple, but I have tested with Test Flight for two months, the build is 24 of version 1.0, and she never crashed on launch.
I use Parse SDK on my app, if this information is important.

Here is the crash log, in device organiser Xcode.

```
Incident Identifier: E9B53C55-88DB-40E3-8BBA-4F86C503A776
CrashReporter Key:   95bf0295ecd50c3c6eaaa238c040d70cc43eb675
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Honi [430]
Path:   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/49FA0CC4-FABB-423F-80B3-724615135FC2/Honi.app/Honi
Identifier:          com.alexlb.Honi
Version:             23 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-01-09 09:46:59.59 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-01-09 09:46:52.52 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100049ea4
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Honi                            0x0000000100049ea4 0x100020000 + 171684
1   Honi                            0x000000010004811c 0x100020000 + 164124
2   UIKit                           0x00000001869fbe50 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100
3   UIKit                           0x00000001869fbdcc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
4   UIKit                           0x00000001869e3a88 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 416
5   UIKit                           0x00000001869fb6e4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 572
6   UIKit                           0x00000001869fb314 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 804
7   UIKit                           0x00000001869f3e30 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 784
8   UIKit                           0x00000001869c44cc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 248
9   UIKit                           0x00000001869c2794 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5528
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c88efc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c88990 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c86690 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181bb5680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
14  GraphicsServices                0x00000001830c4088 GSEventRunModal + 180
15  UIKit                           0x0000000186a2cd90 UIApplicationMain + 204
16  Honi                            0x000000010007fda4 0x100020000 + 392612
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001817568b8 start + 4
```

So, for me, it's possibly one of these reasons.

Reason 1 : It's an Apple problem. I saw something online where a guy explains that after three rejections, Apple accepts his app because there was a problem with their rejections.
I hope it's this.

Reason 2 : I had a little synchron request on my applicationdidBecomeActive, I remove and move her.

Reason 3 : I had no tests in my app, so I deleted MyAppTest in Target in my project.

Reason 4 : In my project, the deployment target was 8.4 and in Targets, it was 8.0 so I put 8.0 for all of this.

I hope someone can help me, and if you want test the app, for maybe performance, I can give you access, because my app build 25 (the newest) with this correction was on testFlight.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I symbolicate this two lines :

```
0   Honi                            0x0000000100049ea4 0x100020000 + 171684
1   Honi                            0x000000010004811c 0x100020000 + 164124
```

For the first :

```
SMSegment.(title.materializeForSet).(closure #1) (in Honi) (SMSegment.swift:61)
Demarrage.(enregistrement(Demarrage) -> (AnyObject) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #2) (in Honi) (Demarrage.swift:180)
```

For the second :

```
Yours.(yes(Yours) -> (AnyObject) -> ()).(closure #1) (in Honi) (Yours.swift:433)
Demarrage.(enregistrement(Demarrage) -> (AnyObject) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #2) (in Honi) (Demarrage.swift:180)
```

But I don't understand, I use SMSegmentView Library (github).

In demarrage line 180, the line is

```
let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
```

For SMSegment line 61 :

```
self.labelWidth = titleText.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height), options:NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin , attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self.label.font], context: nil).size.width"
```

And for Yours line 433 :

```
post.setObject(self.point[entier], forKey: "point")
```

I don't know anymore..